# How to reconfigure Ambari services values with blueprint.json file

Tags: linux, hadoop, json, big-data

we have many Ambari LAB clusters - Apache **Ambari Version 2.5.0.3** , while ambari agent installed on Linux redhat machines

my target is to find a way to update the values of services , on all the Ambari clusters , by automate the process

what we do until now , is take each ambari cluster and change the services values - but this take a lot of time

so if we have diff 25 ambari LAB clusters , then we need access each ambari cluster and change the values , this is very exhausting because we have a lot of values to change ...

but we have a new idea to automate the process

what we thinking is to generate a new blueprint.json from some ambari cluster file as the following:

```
curl -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X GET -u admin:admin http://{ambari_host}:8080/api/v1/clusters/{Cluster_name}\?format\=blueprint >  blueprint.json
```

then update/change the values in the new **blueprint.json** file

and finally upload/push the json file on all clusters

the big question is:

how to upload the new **blueprint.json**  file on ambari cluster ?

is it possible scenario ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may register and upload new blueprint using POST request as follows.

```
curl --verbose -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X POST -u admin:admin http://{ambari_host}:8080/api/v1/blueprints/:{new blueprint name}?validate_topology=false --data  "@./blueprint.json"
```

But this will not change configuration of existing cluster. Blueprints can be used only before creating new cluster.

You may refer [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Modify+configurations) document if you need to modify existing cluster configurations.